A question about Markov chain's definition
Background:
One version of the definition of a discrete-time Markov chain is as follows:
Let $S$ be a countable set. A stochastic process $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is called a discrete-time Markov chain if and only if
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x,y,x_0,...,x_{n-1}\in S$ with $P(Z_0=x_0,...,Z_{n-1}=x_{n-1},Z_n=x)>0$, one has
$$P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_0=x_0,...Z_{n=1}=x_{n-1},Z_n=x)=P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_n=x)=P(Z_1=y|Z_0=x)$$
My question is:
Is
$$
P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_0=x_0,...Z_{n=1}=x_{n-1},Z_n=x)=P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_n=x)
$$
a necessary part of the definition? Can I remove it?
If not, consider that just use
$$P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_0=x_0,...Z_{n=1}=x_{n-1},Z_n=x)=P(Z_1=y|Z_0=x)$$
as the formula in the definition of discrete time of Markov chain, how to show that $$P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_0=x_0,...Z_{n=1}=x_{n-1}, Z_n=x)=P(Z_{n+1}=y|Z_n=x)$$
by the new definition?

It is not necessary: if you know that $$P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid Z_0=x_0,\dots,Z_{n-1}=x_{n-1},Z_n=x)=P(Z_1=y \mid Z_0=x)$$ then you can show that both of those are equal to $P(Z_{n+1}=y\mid Z_n = x)$.
To simplify the notation, let $\vec Z$ stand for $(Z_0, Z_1, \dots, Z_{n-1})$ and let $\vec x$ stand for $(x_0, \dots, x_{n-1})$. Let $p_{xy} = P(Z_1 = y\mid Z_0 = x)$.
Then we assume that for all $\vec x, x, y$ it is true that $$P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid \vec Z = \vec x, Z_n = x) = p_{xy}.$$ By the chain rule for conditional probability, we have
\begin{align}
P(\vec Z=\vec x, Z_n =x, Z_{n+1}=y) 
 &= P(\vec Z=\vec x, Z_n=x) P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid  \vec Z = \vec x, Z_n = x)\\
 &= P(\vec Z=\vec x, Z_n=x) p_{xy}.
\end{align}
If we now sum over all possible $\vec x \in S^n$, then the left-hand side turns into $P(Z_n=x, Z_{n+1}=y)$ and the right-hand side turns into $P(Z_n = x) p_{xy}$. Dividing by $P(Z_n = x)$, we get
$$P(Z_{n+1}=y\mid Z_n=x) = p_{xy}$$ which was what we wanted.

There's an important consequence of this. If instead of summing over all $\vec x \in S^n$, we sum over just a subset of them, we can conclude that $$P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid Z_n = x, A) = p_{xy}$$ for any event $A$ that is defined in terms of $\vec Z$ (in fancier language, any $\vec Z$-measurable event $A$). In other words, if we know $Z_n = x$, then it doesn't matter what we know about $\vec Z$: we can have no information, partial information, or full information about $\vec Z$, and it will not affect our prediction for $Z_{n+1}$.

Given that we can simplify the definition, should we?
In my mind, the two equations

$P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid \vec Z = \vec x, Z_n = x) = P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid Z_n=x)$
$P(Z_{n+1}=y \mid Z_n = x) = P(Z_1 = y \mid Z_0=x)$

are playing different independent roles and should be separated, even though we can combine them into one equation.
The first equation is the memorylessness property of a Markov chain: the knowledge of the immediate past (that $Z_n = x$) makes the distant past (that is, $\vec Z = \vec x$) irrelevant to predicting the future (that $Z_{n+1}=y$). This is the fundamental thing that makes a Markov chain a Markov chain.
The second equation is the time homogeneity of a Markov chain: that is, the transition probability $P(Z_{n+1}=y\mid Z_n = x)$ does not depend on $n$. This is also very important in many uses of Markov chains, but it is not unheard of to consider Markov chains that are not time-homogeneous: that satisfy the first equation, but not the second.

Thanks for your help, sir! I learned a lot. So, the time homogeneity property is a weaker proposition that can be derived from the memorylessness property, but it can't induce the memorylessness property inversely...Is this thought correct?

In principle, they are both separate properties that we can consider, though without memorylessness, the statement of time homogeneity would become more muddled. (Intuitively, though, you can imagine a process that depends on its history in a more complicated way than just the last state - but does so in a consistent way at any time step.)

I got that. Thank you so much for your generous help.

Sorry to bother you, sir. When I reviewed this post today, I got one more question. When I use the law of total probability P(A)=sum of P(B_i)P(A|B_i) to do the proof work above, it seems that I have to roughly consider "Z_{n+1}=y | Z_n=x" as A? Intuitively, I know it makes sense, but I don't how to strictly express it mathematically. Could you help me?

In my experience, the appropriate way to understand a general conditional probability P(A|B) is to consider P(·|B) as a new probability on the sigma-algebra F and consider A as the event concerning the new probability measure P(·|B). So maybe I need to consider a new version of the law of total probability like P(A|B)=sum of P(C_i)P(A|BC_i) concerning C_i?

Yes, that last law of total probability is what we'd need. It's reasonable to be skeptical of this nonstandard law of total probability if you haven't seen it before, and I'm not 100% sure I believe it myself in hindsight, so I decided to rewrite the argument more carefully to avoid it.

This is probably a trivial problem. Thank you very much, professor.
